# In SQL/Vertica how do I return like columns in separate, unrelated tables?

Tags: sql, select, vertica

I have two unrelated tables. Unrelated in the sense that there are no matching columns in both tables that I believe I can join on.

Table_1 houses all the search information our site receives.
Table_2 contains a list of products.

I would like to filter Table_1 search volume based on the products found in Table_2.

Below is some sample data:

Table_1

```
+-----------------+---------------+
|     Keyword     | Search_Volume |
+-----------------+---------------+
| Benedryl        |             1 |
| Rimadyl         |            25 |
| RimadylTablets  |             3 |
| Dog Treats      |            32 |
| Benedryl Liquid |            50 |
| Liquid Benedryl |           100 |
| Cat Food        |           100 |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

Table_2

```
+--------------+
| Product_Name |
+--------------+
| Benedryl     |
| Rimadyl      |
+--------------+
```

Desired_Output

```
+----------+---------------+
| Keyword  | Search Volume |
+----------+---------------+
| Benedryl |           151 |
| Rimadyl  |            28 |
+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you please make the field list more specific?

Comment: Edit your question (or ask a new one) with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of how/why you want those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `like` condition when joining the two tables, and then sum the volumes:

```
SELECT   table2.product_name, SUM(search_volume)
FROM     table2
JOIN     table1 ON table1.keyword LIKE '%' || table2.product_name || '%'
GROUP BY table2.product_name
```